Databricks unable to change workspaces "Could not load workspaces. Try again or contact your administrator."

This is a screenshot of the top right of the screen, the drop down that usually shows all the workspaces. (I redacted the workspace name, I don't know if that matters).
Things seem to be working properly in the workspace I am in, I am able to run commands.
Is there any other way I can try to change workspaces or otherwise troubleshoot this?
